# How can one have elements with different column widths in the same markdown file?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, bootstrap-5, static-site

Say, I have some HTML content like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-7 col-11">
      <p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-11">
      <iframe></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-7 col-11">
      <p>more text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-11">
      <iframe></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do i structure my HTML template file so I can have this in a markdown file (index.md) like this:

```
text

<div class="col-11"><iframe></iframe></div>

more text

<div class="col-11"><iframe></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To structure your HTML template file in a way that allows you to include it in a Markdown file and achieve the desired structure, you can use a custom Markdown extension or a preprocessor that supports this functionality, "Pandoc" is an option.

Pandoc is a command-line tool that can convert files from one markup format to another, including Markdown to HTML and it supports the inclusion of HTML snippets within Markdown files.

Here's how you can structure your files:

Create an HTML template file, let's call it template.html, with the following content:

```
<div class="container">
  <p>{{text1}}</p>
  <div class="col-11">
    <iframe></iframe>
  </div>
  <p>{{text2}}</p>
</div>
```

In this template, {{text1}} and {{text2}} are placeholders for the text content you want to include in your Markdown file.

In your Markdown file (index.md), you can include the HTML template using Pandoc. Here's an example: Note this is ***pseudo-code*** and you will need to define a custom Pandoc filter or use a preprocessor to handle custom directives like !include.

```
text

$include(template.html){.html}

more text
```

Links to documentation on Pandoc filters:

> Pandoc filters: https://pypi.org/project/pandocfilters/

> Pandoc !include: https://pypi.org/project/pandoc-include/

The $include(template.html){.html} directive tells Pandoc to include the contents of the template.html file at that position. The .html class is optional and is used to specify that the included content should be treated as HTML.

To generate the final HTML output, you can use the following Pandoc command:

```
pandoc index.md -o output.html
```

This command converts the index.md file to HTML format and saves the result in output.html.

By using Pandoc and the $include directive, you can include the HTML template within your Markdown file and achieve the desired structure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).